# TypeError: ... is not a constructor ERROR with JEST

Tags: node.js, ts-jest

I'm not sure if my CognitoService class is being exported as expected to my JEST configuration because I'm still having this issue. I tried changing the way that the class is being exported without any good results, also I reviewed my jest.config.js several times but everything seems to be ok, any ideas?

This is the issue on my test console (jest):

```
TypeError: cognito_utils_1.CognitoService is not a constructor

      23 |     );
      24 |
    > 25 |   const cognitoService: CognitoService = new CognitoService(
         |                                          ^
      26 |     COGNITO_URL,
      27 |     COGNITO_USERS_CLIENT_ID,
```

this is my unit test: **index.test.ts**

```
import { handler } from './index';
import { Context, APIGatewayProxyCallback } from 'aws-lambda';

import { CognitoService } from '@mylib/cognito-utils';

const createMockContext = (): Context => ({
  ...
});

const createMockCallback = (): APIGatewayProxyCallback => (error, result) => {};

describe('handler', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  
  });
  
  it('should return ...', async () => {
    const event = {
      httpMethod: 'PUT',
      request: {
        ...
      }
    };


    // HERE IS THE ERROR /////////////////////////////////////

    const mockGetUserBySub = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(null);
    
    jest.mock('@mylib/cognito-utils', () => {
      return {
        CognitoService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                getUserBySub: mockGetUserBySub
            }
        })
      }   
    });

    // HERE IS THE ERROR /////////////////////////////////////

    const context = createMockContext();
    const callback = createMockCallback();

    const result = await handler(event, context, callback);

    expect(result.statusCode).toBe(404);
    expect(result.body).toEqual(JSON.stringify({ message: 'User not found in cognito' }));
  });

});
```

this is the handler that I want to test: **index.ts**

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';

import { CognitoService } from '@mylib/cognito-utils';

export const handler: Handler = async (event) => {

  const cognitoService: CognitoService = new CognitoService(
    COGNITO_URL,
    COGNITO_USERS_CLIENT_ID,
    COGNITO_USERS_POOL_ID,
    COGNITO_REGION,
  );

  const { id: userId } = await cognitoService.getUserBySub('123123');

  if (!userId) {
    return {
      statusCode: 404,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'User not found in cognito' }),
    };
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 404,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: userId }),
  };
};
```

and this is my cognitoService class: **cognito-service.ts**

```
import {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    CognitoIdentityProviderClientConfig,
  } from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';
  import { UserMetadataAttributes } from '@mylib/models-common';
  
  export class CognitoService {
    identityProviderClient: CognitoIdentityProviderClient;
  
    constructor(
      private COGNITO_URL: string,
      private COGNITO_CLIENT_ID: string,
      private COGNITO_POOL_ID: string,
      private COGNITO_REGION: string,
    ) {
      const config: CognitoIdentityProviderClientConfig = {
        region: COGNITO_REGION,
        endpoint: COGNITO_URL,
      };
      this.identityProviderClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(config);
    }
  
    async getUserBySub(sub: string): Promise<UserMetadataAttributes> {
      if (sub) {
        ...
      }
      throw new Error('User sub required');
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: Where you `jest.mock('@mylib/cognito-utils'`, your mocked value is called `CognitoService1` (with a `1` at the end). `CognitoService` would then be `undefined`.

Comment: @EricHaynes typo issue, sorry. I update the answer. Same result with that fix. Thanks for looking that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `jest.mock` inside of a test. It has to be a the top level. How jest's mocking actually works under the hood is:

- read your whole file
- extract all of the `jest.mock` statements
- hack the mocked value in into the node require cache
- rewrite the test file without those mock statements
- execute the rewritten file

Note that this also adds an implicit constraint that you can't reference values outside of the mock function (with some caveats around `const`, but life will be easier if you just assume there are no exceptions :) )

Try something like:

```js
import { CognitoService } from '@mylib/cognito-utils'

jest.mock('@mylib/cognito-utils', () => {
  return {
    // just mock the constructor
    CognitoService: jest.fn(),
  }
})

describe('handler', () => {
  let mockCognitoService: jest.Mocked<CognitoService>

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockCognitoService = {
      getUserBySub: jest.fn(),
    } as any // <--- cast not needed unless your real class has more methods
    ;(CognitoService as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => mockCognitoService)
  })

  it('whatever', async () => {
    mockCognitoService.getUserBySub.mockResolvedValueOnce(null)
    // ...
  })
})
```

Also note that if there are other things in that lib that you don't want to mock, you can preserve them like:

```js
jest.mock('@mylib/cognito-utils', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@mylib/cognito-utils')
    CognitoService: jest.fn(),
  }
})
```

Additional $0.02; your class doesn't actually allow `null` as a result. If you're mocking this case, then you likely don't have strict mode enabled. You should *really* consider doing that. It eliminates whole classes of errors around incorrect types, including null/undefined. Half of the language is disabled without it, resulting in code that's not valid JS, and not valid TS either.